# How to use fullCalendar.formatDate with event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I am trying to use `formatDate` with the event object from `eventMouseOver` and can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var stDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent, "MM-dd-yyyyy");
    tooltip.show('test tooltip');
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`formatDate` expectes a date, not an event:

```
var stDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'MM-dd-yyyyy');
```

Comment: @Smith - this comment was added long before V2 came out (its still in beta, as of today)